# How to convert meters into feet and inches

Tags: c#

Creating a program and I have been struggling to convert metres to feet and inches, but I finally got it working I think.

My issue now is with the variable inchesleft it is a int and I am struggling to work out how to make it an integer as I want to drop the remainder of the inches value so I can get a value of 6feet 4inches etc.

code below:

```
double inft, convert, inchesleft, value = 0.3048;
int ft;
string input;

Console.WriteLine("please enter amount of metres");
input = Console.ReadLine();
convert = double.Parse(input);

inft = convert / value;
ft = (int)inft;
inchesleft = convert / value % 1 *12;


Console.WriteLine("{0} feet {1} inches.", ft, inchesleft);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: "My issue now is with the variable inchesleft it is a int" - no it isn't... it's a `double`. Look at where it's being declared. (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend declaring variables at the point of first use, rather than declaring everything at the start.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
double inft, convert, value = 0.3048;
int ft, inchesleft;
string input;

Console.WriteLine("please enter amount of metres");
input = Console.ReadLine();
convert = double.Parse(input);
```

Divide the input number by 0.3048 to get Feet

```
inft = convert / value;
```

Now we got Feet in decimal. Fetch the left part of feet (before decimal point)

```
ft = (int)inft;
```

Fetch the right part of Feet (after decimal point) and divide it by 0.08333 to convert it into Inches

```
double temp = (inft - Math.Truncate(inft)) / 0.08333;
```

Now we got inches in decimal. Fetch the left part of Inches (before decimal point)

```
inchesleft = (int)temp; // to be more accurate use temp variable which contains the decimal point value of inches 

Console.WriteLine("{0} feet {1} inches.", ft, inchesleft);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some parts of @Waqar Ahmed method above & tweaked it slightly. Thanks man.

```
//-----METHODS
        //VARIABLES
        double inchFeet;
        int wholeFeet;

    public double GetHeightFeet()
    {
        //CENTIMETERS TO FEET
        //PlayerHeight is ___cm input
        inchFeet = (PlayerHeight / 0.3048) / 100;
        //LEFT PART BEFORE DECIMAL POINT. WHOLE FEET
        wholeFeet = (int)inchFeet;
        return wholeFeet;
    }

    public double GetHeightInches()
    {
        //DECIMAL OF A FOOT TO INCHES TEST HEIGHT 181cm to see if 11''
        double inches = Math.Round((inchFeet - wholeFeet) / 0.0833);
        return inches;
    }
```